# TikZ matrix : put frames around nodes but preventing edges to overlap

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I can't figure out how to prevent each border to overlap on others, on the MWE below. If someone has an idea...

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \footnotesize
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
               nodes={rectangle, draw=gray, minimum height=2em, minimum width=2em,
                      anchor=center, align=center,
                      inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}]
  {
    1 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 10 \\
    11 & 11 & 11 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 13 & 13 & 13 & 14 & \node [draw, circle, thick, blue] {14} ; \\
    14 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 17 & 17 & 18 & 18 & 18 & 18 & 19 \\
    19 & 20 & 20 & 20 & 23 & 26 & 29 & 29 & 31 & 32 & 32 & 34\\
  } ;
  \draw [thick, red] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-13.north east) -- (m-1-13.south east) -- (m-2-11.north east) -- (m-2-11.south east) -- (m-2-1.south west) --  (m-1-1.north west)  ;
  \draw [thick, orange] (m-3-1.north west) -- (m-3-12.north east) -- (m-4-12.south east) -- (m-4-1.south west) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `row sep=\pgflinewidth, column sep=\pgflinewidth`, if you mean that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the `row sep` and `column sep` suitably. Now they are `-\pgflinewidth` making them overlap. Make the `\pgflinewidth` or even `2\pgflinewidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \footnotesize
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, row sep=2\pgflinewidth, column sep=2\pgflinewidth,
               nodes={rectangle, draw=gray, minimum height=2em, minimum width=2em,
                      anchor=center, %align=center,
                      inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}]
  {
    1 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 10 \\
    11 & 11 & 11 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 13 & 13 & 13 & 14 & \node [draw, circle, thick, blue] {14} ; \\
    14 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 17 & 17 & 18 & 18 & 18 & 18 & 19 \\
    19 & 20 & 20 & 20 & 23 & 26 & 29 & 29 & 31 & 32 & 32 & 34\\
  } ;
  \draw [thick, red] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-13.north east) -- (m-1-13.south east) -- (m-1-11.south east) -- (m-2-11.south east) -- (m-2-1.south west) --  (m-1-1.north west)  ;
  \draw [thick, orange] (m-3-1.north west) -- (m-3-12.north east) -- (m-4-12.south east) -- (m-4-1.south west) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have changed `(m-2-11.north east)` to `(m-1-11.south east)` additionally in the red line.

Comment: I've just noticed that the numbers are not perfectly centered : do you have any idea to fix it ? Thanks.

Comment: @natsirt: I got it. Remove that `align=center` from the options. :)

Comment: Eeeerk -_-' ! Sounds weird, yet OK.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Harish, his solution is simple and efficient. I lost myself through my iterations in typesetting this table.
I ended up with this solution, which works too, but is rather inelegant. The good point is I don't have "double lines" :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \footnotesize
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
               nodes={rectangle, draw=gray, minimum height=2em, minimum width=2em,
                      anchor=center, align=center,
                      inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}]{
  1 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 10 \alt<3->{\\
  11 & 11 & 11 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 13 & 13 & 13 & 14 & \node [draw, circle, thick, blue, minimum size=1ex] {14} ; }{\\
  11 & 11 & 11 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 13 & 13 & 13 & 14 & 14 }\\
  14 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 17 & 17 & 18 & 18 & 18 & 18 & 19 \\
  19 & 20 & 20 & 20 & 23 & 26 & 29 & 29 & 31 & 32 & 32 & 34\\ } ;
  \draw<2-> [thick, red] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-13.north east) -- (m-1-13.south east) -- (m-2-11.north east) -- ($ (m-2-11.south east)!.03!(m-2-11.north east) $) -- ($ (m-2-1.south west)!.015!(m-1-1.north west) $) -- cycle  ;
  \draw<2-> [thick, orange] (m-3-1.north west) -- (m-3-12.north east) -- (m-4-12.south east) -- (m-4-1.south west) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```